# i am getting always value as "on" instead of original value while reading form the radio button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i am getting always  value as "on" instead of original value while reading form the radio button.
    i want to access the value of the radio button . can some one help me to get the actual value from radio button .
    below is the code snippet i used to get the value.

```
 $("#answerToQuest input:radio[name='options']:checked").val();
```

or

options is radio button group    my div id

```
$('input[name=options]:checked', '#answerToQuest').val()
```

thanks in advance !
    Kamesh

Comment: can you post your `html` code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
 $("#answerToQuest :radio:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get using

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){      
        alert($('input[name=q12_3]:checked').val());
    });
});
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkH8n/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issues too. This happens mainly because the radio button has no value for itself at all like the mark-up below:

```
<label for="car">
    <input type="radio" id="car" name="options" />Car</label>
<br/>
<label for="bike">
    <input type="radio" id="bike" name="options" />Bike</label>
```

So, if you try this [**Fiddle Demo #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/9zXYw/), you will see that you are getting the alert as "on" on clicking the radio buttons.

I resolved this issue (*based on the HTML markup I have*), by the code below:

```
$("input:radio[name=theme]").change(function () {
    var value = this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
    alert(value);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/9zXYw/1/)